# Python error with init.tcl after Inno Setup Compiler

Tags: python-2.7, installation, tcl, inno-setup, py2exe

I have a program which I converted with py2exe to an exe. After that I tried to make an installer with Inno Setup. I included all necessary files like .dll, .pyd, .gif, .wav, the tlc folder (tcl8.5, tk8.5) etc. But after installing the program it gives me this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\test>test.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9359, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 11, in __init__
  File "Tkinter.pyc", line 1745, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    {C:/Program Files (x86)/lib/tcl8.5} {C:/Program Files (x86)/lib/tcl8.5} C:/l
ib/tcl8.5 {C:/Program Files (x86)/library} C:/library C:/tcl8.5.2/library C:/tcl
8.5.2/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So where was `init.tcl` installed to?

Comment: @DonalFellows Like the other files too it was installed in Program Files (x86). There it is in tcl8.5

Answer (score 2):

This solved the problem I had. I've created my Inno Setup (v5.5.5) outside the py2exe output dir named `dest` (v0.6.9 win32).

Py2exe output `dest` contains one dir named `tcl` which contains files and subfolders. So in your Inno Setup script add the following entry to the `[Files]` section:

```
Source: dest\tcl\*; DestDir: "{app}\tcl"; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs
```

In my case `currentWorkingdir\` is added to `dest\tcl\*`. This gets everything and sends it to `DestDir: "(app)\tcl\"` which gets the files and folders.

Flags `createallsubdirs` and `recursesubdirs` does all the work. This is an excerpt from help:

> **createallsubdirs**
>
> By default the compiler skips empty directories when it recurses
> subdirectories searching for the Source filename/wildcard. This flag
> causes these directories to be created at install time (just like if
> you created [Dirs] entries for them).
>
> Must be combined with recursesubdirs.

Comment: this answer didn't make sense to me, because i got the identical error message but my files were in the correct directories.   out of frustration, i tried it, simply changing:
    DestDir: "{app}"  to:
    DestDir: "{app}\tcl"
solved the problem beautifully, but i don't understand why.... ;-(